# Sql Azure Database Backup and Restore using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-sql-database, dac

I am working on Sql Azure Database Backup and restore functionality.

Question:
- Can we Backup more than one database into a single bacpac file using "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac"
- Can we read the bacpac file in our C# so that we can know which database backup is this.
- Can we restore more than one database at a time.
- Can we override the existing database using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.

I am able to take one database backup, restore (not override) using "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac".

I searched in google find the above questions answer but failed to get any solutions.

Please suggest

Is there any way to take backup/restore and override the bacpac file in sql Azure using C#.

Comment: With C# alone u'll not be happy in Azure. All operations in the new Azure Resource Manager can be called by PowerShell and Azure CmdLets. But you can execute the CmdLets with C#. However I do not know any command which provides this functionality. And IIRC a bacpac file does not provide the opportunity to backup multiple databases.

Comment: @Ben can we take backup/restore multiple database using PowerShell or Azure CmdLets

Answer (score 1):

.bacpac files for Azure SQL Database are scoped to individual databases and their currently is no way backup two databases in a single .bacpac file.